# Show gas used in solidity

Tags: solidity, gas

I want to return the gas used to the user when he uses a payable function.
I used tx.gasprice but it always returns 1.

How can I get the actual gas used value (not the maximum or user set values, but really the gas used value for the transaction, in my case, a function call)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can measure the gas used in a block of code by calculating the difference between `gasleft()` at the start and `gasleft()` at the end:

```
function test() returns (uint256 gasUsed)
{
    uint256 startGas = gasleft();

    // ...some code here...

    gasUsed = startGas - gasleft();
}
```

This does not yet take into account the constant cost of a transaction, which as far as I know is usually approximately `21000`.

Comment: Is it possible to get the like "startgas" within solidity and without web3 or external calls?

Comment: This actually a good idea and this is available in the solidity environment, no need for web3.

Comment: @Jaime what I wrote was just an example. For sure I had some other functions that should work with gas. But I didn't want to talk detailed about it.

Comment: @Jaime im working through a similar implementation thats not giving me the expected results: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/111741/how-can-i-measure-gas-in-solidity-to-increment-a-users-balance-according-to-the

Answer (score 6):

tx.gasPrice is the price per 1 gas, not the gas paid. There is no way to get this information from the variables in the environment in solidity. The solution is to have a frontend app that sends this info to your contract.

Hope this help.

Comment: It helps but the problem is, I want to work with that value within solidity itself, so use it in functions. Is that in no way possible?

Comment: No, as far as I know. The only option is to use web3 and send this info to your contract. Then you can read the value it as any other variable.

Comment: the answer from @Jesse Busman is what you need

Answer (score 1):

use getTransactionReceipt: [doc](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=getTransaction#gettransactionreceipt)

Comment: Hello, I meant in solidity. Not web3. Is that possible?

Comment: This link is not the answer. This is web3js, he asked for solidity