# How can I measure gas in solidity to increment a user's balance according to the amount of gas spent to call the function?

Tags: solidity, gas-estimate

I have a function that I am calling and based on the logic of that function and how much gas it spends to execute the function, I want to increment a user's balance to reimburse the user for the gas expended on the function call.

Here is an attempt that I am working through using a combination of `gasleft()` and `tx.gasprice` that is failing at the moment.

**How can I come to a rough approximation to the amount of gas in Wei/Eth that a function expends during the life of its execution in a solidity contract?**

```
    function aFxn2RefundGas(address gamer) external {
        uint256 begin = gasleft();
        ...
        
        uint256 end = gasleft();
        
        if (users.length > 100) {
            // pay startMultiplier * gas fees to the person who clicked
            balances[address(this)] = balances[address(this)] - (((begin - end) + 21000) * tx.gasprice) * startMultiplier;
            balances[gamer] = balances[gamer] + (((begin - end) + 21000) * tx.gasprice) * startMultiplier;
        } else {
            //
            // pay startMultiplier * gas fees to the person who clicked
            balances[address(this)] = balances[address(this)] - (((begin - end) + 21000) * tx.gasprice);
            balances[gamer] = balances[gamer] + (((begin - end) + 21000) * tx.gasprice);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the issue with the code?

Comment: doesn't increment the balance with the difference coming back from the gasleft() executions @Jaime